Subclasses init method
I have a question regarding the init method for subclasses in Python.

In the image above, a child class Developer is being defined from a parent class Employee. In Developer, the __init__ method is defined using super().__init__ (i.e the __init__ method of the parent class) and an extra attribute prog_lang is being added that is not in the parent class. This I understand. However, in the following example:

A child class App is being defined form the parent class tk.Tk from the tkinter module. Here, the same super().__init__ method is being used, which gives all the attributes from the parent class to the instances of the child class upon being instanced. However, then, rather than writing "extra" attributes with an equal sign, as in the previous example, which would look something like this:
self.title = 'Classed based app'
self.geometry = '600x600'
...

We instead have:
self.title('Classed based app')
self.geometry('600x600')
...

My question to test my understanding: is this because the constructor method of parent class tk.Tk already has a title and geometry attribute, which are set to some default values if none is entered upon generating an instance of the class? Moreover, the parent class tk.Tk also has a method title that sets a new value to the instance's title attribute. Something along this sketch:
class Tk:
def __init__(self, title = default,...)
     self.title = title
     ....


def title(self, new_title):
    self.title = new_title

Therefore, in the constructor method for the child class App, using the equal sign to set the attribute (self.title = 'Classes based app') and using the method (self.title('Classes based app')) are equivalent.
I have tried looking for the tk.Tk() class "manual" online, but have not found it.
I leave the links of the YouTube videos of where the screenshots are from:

Img1
Img2


Can you post all your code and inputs and expected outputs as text in your question? See here.

(self.title = 'Classes based app') and using the method (self.title('Classes based app')) are equivalent. - OK then, what's wrong with that?

@ScaryWombat nothing's wrong with that. I just wanted to check if I was understanding how the code work correctly.

tkinter is not written in python and you're stuck with whatever the binding did to expose its functionality to python. In this case, title and etc.. are setter methods, not vanilla attributes. The title is actually held in the underlying tcl object. You could add print(self.title) and you'll see its a bound method.
When you write your own class, you are free to use vanilla attributes, @property methods or your own getter and setter methods. In your Developer code, we don't know whether prog_lang is an attribute or a property with a setter method managed by python. In fact, it could be an attribute today and you could change your mind and make it a property tomorrow.
When you use tkinter, self.title = 'class based app' does not set the tk title because the method wasn't called. And it masks the title method which could cause bugs in the future.

Thank you for your answer :) . I am a beginner / intermediate at programming so I am not sure I understand everything you are saying but I do think I understand some parts.
